# Create style that displays the area under the curve with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles

I currently have this code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\definecolor{linecolor1}{HTML}{3DC6F3}
\pgfplotsset{integration/.style={color=linecolor1,mark=none,line width=0.5pt,solid}}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    ticks=none,
    axis line style={->},
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    samples=1000,
  },
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-2,xmax=4,
        ymin=-2,ymax=8,
      ]
      \addplot[integration]{-(1/4)*x*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x-4)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which creates the following
[image]

How can I create the `integration` style to shade the area under the curve?

Comment: Alright. Made my question clearer.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You seem to be asking two [or more] unrelated questions, here. On TeX.SX, we try to keep unrelated questions on separate pages. If you have multiple questions that are unrelated to one another, you should ask each in a separate TeX.SX "question". You'll stand a better chance of getting a satisfactory answer to each of your questions.

Comment: Important: When using PGFPlots always set version(compat) : `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to fill everything below the curve add `fill=blue!30` to `integration/.style`. If it should be filled between the curve and the x-axis, see below.

#### Adaptations

**Variant 1**

- add second plot at 0 (`\addplot [name path=xaxis]  {0}`) OR

  - if it is excactly the x-axis just set `x axis line style={name path=xaxis}` (see comment by [hpekristiansen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/8650/hpekristiansen))
- give the function a name with `name path` (e.g., `curve`)
- add `\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}` that defines the `fill between` command:

  ```
  \addplot[fill=blue!30] fill between[of=curve and xaxis];
  ```

**Variant 2**

- use `fill=blue!30` directly on the plot and add `\closedcycle` (this will draw a line over the x-axis) (see comment by [hpekristiansen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/8650/hpekristiansen))

#### Result

Variant 1:

[image]

Variant 2:

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\definecolor{linecolor1}{HTML}{3DC6F3}
\pgfplotsset{
    integration/.style={color=linecolor1,mark=none,line width=0.5pt,solid},
    every axis/.append style={
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        ticks=none,
        axis line style={->},
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        samples=1000,
        x axis line style={name path=xaxis},
    },
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-2,xmax=4,
            ymin=-2,ymax=8,
            domain=-5:5,
        ]
            % variant 1:
            \addplot [name path=curve, integration]{-(1/4)*x*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x-4)};
            \addplot [fill=blue!30] fill between[of=curve and xaxis];
            %
            % variant 2:
            %\addplot [name path=curve, integration, fill=blue!30]{-(1/4)*x*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x-4)} \closedcycle;
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. One would normally not want to add extra plots. This messes with the legend and gives problem with the domain used with larger limits. -add lots of extra points, line segments -worse compile time and output. Use e.g. `x axis line style={name path=xaxis}`.

Comment: Is there a way to have the integration style fill in the curve for me so I don't have to add an extra line? Also, like @hpekristiansen suggested, I'm using `x axis line style={name path=xaxis}` and `y axis line style={name path=yaxis}` so I don't have to create another plot. Also, quick note, is it alright if I provide the name of the curve in the integration style?

Comment: Yes: - add `name path=function` to the style. I tried and failed to add the fill plot to the style with `execute at end plot` - but that is not allowed. An other alternative is to have the fill in the plot itself: `\addplot[integration, fill=cyan!30]{-(1/4)*x*(x+2)*(x-1)*(x-4)} \closedcycle;` (Does not use `fillbetween` - the problem here is that the function(path) is also drawn along the x axis).

Comment: @hpekristiansen thanks for the suggestions. I added it as a variant to the answer.